# Android studio generating new DaggerComponet.java file

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I have defined my Dagger2 component file in a class named LpComponent.java so I need to instantiate things using DaggerLpComponent class reference.

However when I update LpComponent.java file DaggerLpComponent is not getting recreated , only way I can get this is to clean the whole project, and rebuild it.

Is there good old make style dependency I can specify DaggerLpComponent.java depends on LpComponent.java?

Also its not clear to be what rule generates DaggerLpComponent.java file. I have tried ./gradlew tasks to see if there is some dagger specific task that generates the file, but didn't see anything..

Answer (score 1):

Dagger 2 works via annotation processing, which happens at compile time.  A simple compilation of your project should trigger the Dagger 2 annotation processor to run and generate new sources.  With Android, that should be minimally one of the tasks starting with "compile" that has your build type and flavor in the name.